# Why inverse fft doesnt match with original signal

Tags: python, scipy, fft

I have an audio wav file which has some vocals recorded. I have used scipy.read to digitize the wav file. I have calculated the FFT and then i get the inverse FFT from it.
When i plot the original signal and inverse FFT overlapped. They match exactly.
But when i plot the datasets of the original signal and the inverse FFT, they dont match at all.
I observed that this is happening only with a file having vocals, the same with an instrumental recording works fine.

Below is the code i have tried:

```
import scipy.io.wavfile as wavfile
import scipy
import scipy.fftpack as fftpack
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import csv
import numpy as np
fs_rate, signal = wavfile.read("Sa.wav")
print ("Frequency sampling", fs_rate," Hz")
l_audio = len(signal.shape)
print ("Channels", l_audio,"Audio data shape",signal.shape,"l_audio",l_audio)
if l_audio == 2:
    signal = signal.sum(axis=1) / 2
N = signal.shape[0]
length = N / fs_rate
print ("Duration of audio wav file in secs", length,"Samples chosen",signal.shape[0])
time =np.linspace(0, length, signal.shape[0])
sampling_interval=time[1]-time[0]

inverse_fft_amplitude = scipy.ifft(scipy.fft(signal)) 
plt.xlabel('Time[s]')
plt.ylabel('Amplitude')
plt.plot(time, signal, 'blue', time, inverse_fft_amplitude , 'red')
plt.legend(('Original Signal', 'Reconstructed Signal using Inverse FFT'))
# They match exactly same

#Getting the data points for original signal
df = pd.DataFrame({"Time" : time, "Amplitude" : signal})
df.to_csv("OriginalData.csv", header=None, index=False)

#Getting the data points for inverse FFT signal
df = pd.DataFrame({"Time" : time, "Amplitude" : abs(inverse_fft_amplitude)})
df.to_csv("ReconstructedDataSet.csv",  header=None,index=False)
```

Overlapping of Original signal and Inverse FFT
[image]

Overlapping original signal and inverse FFT data sets
[image]

Comment: The bottom of your code is missing.  We don't see your second graph, so it's uncertain what precisely is going on.  Are you claiming we don't see any 'blue' in the first graph because it it is completely covered by the 'red'?  Can you show the two on separate plots so we can be certain that's precisely what's going on?

Comment: `ifft` returns complex values. The imaginary part should be close to 0 (identical zero except for numerical rounding errors). Pyplot plots the real part only, so you see the right results. The other plot likely shows the magnitude, and hence only has non-negative values. Do `scipy.ifft(...).real()`.